# Nodejs - async/await - nested async calls without await is still blocking?

Tags: node.js, async-await, nested, nonblocking

I would expect the saveData() call in datafx not block anything as there is no "await" but when i check the logs and timestamps i notice that the "main done" log is delayed even though "retrieved data" is not.

```
async function mainCaller(){
  // do something and then trigger call to get data
  let id = 13;
  let data = await datafx( id );  <-- this gets blocked for saveData() - why?
  LOG( `main done` );
}

async function datafx( id ){
  // get data
  let data = await getData( id );
  // cleanup data
  // save data but don't wait for it
    // datafx does not wait for it as expected
    // however, mainCaller() is somehow "delayed" by it based on log timestamps
  saveData(id, data );
  LOG( `retrieved data` );
  return data;
}

async function getData(id){ return await dbRead(id); }
async function saveData(id, data){ return await dbSave(id, data); }
```

1. Is the "await" in the mainCaller() awaiting all async calls, including the nested ones?
2. Is that correct?
3. Is there a better way to implement the nested async call to avoid the delay on the caller?
4. i can confirm that the "saveData()" call is impacting as i removed it and i see the mainCaller continue without delay as soon as datafx returns.

Comment: `saveData()` return promise and you didn't await, so it print `'main done'`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code -

```
function timeoutPromise(interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("done");
    }, interval);
  });
};

async function timeTest1() {
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
}

async function timeTest3() {
 await timeoutPromise(3000);
}

async function timeTest2() {
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  timeTest3();
}

async function test1() {
  let startTime = Date.now();
  await timeTest1();
  let finishTime = Date.now();
  let timeTaken = finishTime - startTime;
  console.log("Time taken for test1 in milliseconds: " + timeTaken);
}

async function test2() {
  let startTime = Date.now();
  await timeTest2();
  let finishTime = Date.now();
  let timeTaken = finishTime - startTime;
  console.log("Time taken for test2 in milliseconds: " + timeTaken);
}

async function test3() {
  let startTime = Date.now();
  timeTest1();
  let finishTime = Date.now();
  let timeTaken = finishTime - startTime;
  console.log("Time taken for test3 in milliseconds: " + timeTaken);
}

test1();
test2();
test3();
```

The output of this program is as follows -

```
Time taken for test3 in milliseconds: 0
Time taken for test2 in milliseconds: 3004
Time taken for test1 in milliseconds: 6008
```

Answers to your questions are as follows -

> Is the "await" in the `mainCaller()` awaiting all async calls, including the nested ones?

Consider function `test2` in the example code mentioned above, the answer is **no**.

> Is there a better way to implement the nested async call to avoid the
> delay on the caller?

Yes, you need to remove `await` from `mainCaller` while calling `datafx` function, same as described in function `test3`

Comment: The scenario I am referring to in my question is the test2() - "Time taken for test2 in milliseconds: 3004", and that's how I expected it to behave. However, I am observing as if test2() waits on the "timeoutPromise(3000)" to complete and reporting 6000ms time taken for test2.

Comment: @Aikh, I have updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: OP, does the new answer help you? If so, could you please accept it?

Comment: test2() take `3s` isn't correct, it includes timeTest3() which isn't measured.